# render option in select failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with doing this

```
    <option key={this.props.floors} value={this.props.floors.floor_id}>
        {this.props.floors.name}
    </option>
```

This is my data

```
[{
    "floor_id": "1",
    "name": "UG"
}, {
    "floor_id": "2",
    "name": "G"
}, {
    "floor_id": "3",
    "name": "LG"
}]
```

I didn't see any option been population in my dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floors is an `array` which contains the option data, in order to create the `ui` from this `array`, you need to use any `loop` to iterate the `array`, Check this example by using `map`:

```js
var floors = [{
    "floor_id": "1",
    "name": "UG"
}, {
    "floor_id": "2",
    "name": "G"
}, {
    "floor_id": "3",
    "name": "LG"
}]

class App extends React.Component{

   render(){
      return <select>
                 {
                    this.props.floors.map(floor => <option key={floor.floor_id} value={floor.floor_id}>
                                                      {floor.name}
                                                   </option>)
                 }
             </select>
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App floors = {floors}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map over the props and retun the option field like

```
<select>
{
    this.props.floors.map((item) => {
         return (
              <option key={item.floor_id} value={item.floor_id}>
        {item.name}
    </option>
         )
     })
}
</select>
```

sample snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var floors = [{
    "floor_id": "1",
    "name": "UG"
}, {
    "floor_id": "2",
    "name": "G"
}, {
    "floor_id": "3",
    "name": "LG"
}]
        return (
        <select>
            {
                floors.map((item) => {
                     return (
                          <option key={item.floor_id} value={item.floor_id}>
                    {item.name}
                </option>
                     )
                 })
            }
            </select>
        )

    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```